# How do I use Javascript to check if the LP tokens of a solana liquidity pool is locked and burnt?

Tags: web3js, solana-web3js

I have the mint addresses of two tokens on solana and their pair address. Using javascript, I want to know if the liquidity of the pool is locked and burnt. Thanks

This is what I've tried:

```
  const info = await connection.getAccountInfo(
    new PublicKey(pooladdress)
  );
  if (!info) return;

  const poolState = LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(info.data);
  console.log("poolState=============", poolState);
};

const SOL_USDC_POOL_ID = "58oQChx4yWmvKdwLLZzBi4ChoCc2fqCUWBkwMihLYQo2";

getPoolInfo(SOL_USDC_POOL_ID);
```

I would appreciate pointers in the right direction.

Comment: This is something I've also been trying to figure out. One thought I had was checking for any transactions post-mint that are going to a burn address. Surprised that there isn't more documentation on this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

Get the LP mints and reserve of the pool:

```
const acc = await connection.getMultipleAccountsInfo([new 
PublicKey("pool address")])
const parsed = acc.map((v) => LIQUIDITY_STATE_LAYOUT_V4.decode(v.data))

const lpMint = parsed[0].lpMint
const lpReserve = parsed[0].lpReserve
```

Get the mint info:

```
const accInfo = await connection.getParsedAccountInfo(new solana.PublicKey(lpMint));
const mintInfo = accInfo?.value?.data?.parsed?.info
```

Calculate:

```
const lpReserve = lpReserve / Math.pow(10, mintInfo?.decimals)
const actualSupply = mintInfo?.supply / Math.pow(10, mintInfo?.decimals)
console.log(`lpMint: ${lpMint}, Reserve: ${lpReserve}, Actual Supply: ${actualSupply}`);

//Calculate burn percentage
const maxLpSupply = Math.max(actualSupply, (lpReserve - 1));
const burnAmt = (lpReserve - actualSupply)
console.log(`burn amt: ${burnAmt}`)
const burnPct = (burnAmt / lpReserve) * 100;
console.log(`${burnPct} LP burned`);
```